# how to call a oracle procedure from shell with parameter

Tags: oracle, shell, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which adds two numbers.I want to call that procedure from shell.i can call procedure without argument.For ex

```
 create or replace procedure printTheName
  is 
  begin
 dbms_output.put_line('This is a procedure'):
 end;
 /
```

this is the procedure which prints a  message. i can call it from shell using this

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlplus -s system/oracle10g@orcl<<END
execute printTheName();
commit;
```

This is running fine Now i have  a procedure which adds two numbers i have to call that from shell this is the procedure.

```
declare
  a number(2);
  b number(2);
  c number(2);
begin
  a:=&a;
  b:=&b;
  c:=a+b;
  dbms_output.put_line(a|| ' + '||b||' = '||c);
end;
```

Comment: So, why are you having problems calling this procedure? What are you trying to do at the moment?

Comment: i am doing #!/bin/sh
sqlplus -s system/oracle10g@orcl<<END
execute printTheName(10,10);
commit;

Comment: You can try this : `echo "execute printTheName(10,10);" | sqlplus system/oracle10g@orcl`

Comment: @OuldAbba thanks a lot its running fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *pipe* to pass commands to *sqlplus*

```sh
echo "execute printTheName(10,10);
commit;
execute procedure2();
" | sqlplus system/oracle10g@orcl
```

note that you cant put as many *sqlplus* commands as you want inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Lucifer, to redirect to output:

```
{ 
echo "execute printTheName(10,10);
commit;
execute procedure2();
" | sqlplus system/oracle10g@orcl 
} > fileout.txt
```